# How to use a role's default value through `hostvars`

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm trying to create a role inspired by this one: [ansible-cassandra](https://github.com/andrewrothstein/ansible-cassandra).

In this role, there is a default value for variable `cassandra_network_iface`:

```
cassandra_network_iface: eth0
```

And a template file *cassandra.yaml.j2* that use it through `hostvars`:

```
...
- seeds: "{% for host in groups[cassandra_ansible_groupname] %}{{hostvars[host]['ansible_' + hostvars[host]['cassandra_network_iface']]['ipv4']['address']}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
...
```

When I use this template file with a task:

```
- name: configure...
  template: >-
    src=cassandra.yaml.j2
    dest=/tmp/cassandra.yaml
    mode=0644
```

I have this error:

```
fatal: [...]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'cassandra_network_iface'"}
```

The problem is variable `cassandra_network_iface` is not defined into `hostvars[host]` scope (I checked that with a debug task), otherwise I can use it directly.

My question: is there a way to reach variable `cassandra_network_iface` through `hostvars` ?

Note: I tried with ansible 2.1 and 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access roles' default var via hostvars.

Try:

```
- seeds: "{% for host in groups[cassandra_ansible_groupname] %}{{hostvars[host]['ansible_' + (hostvars[host]['cassandra_network_iface']|default(cassandra_network_iface))]['ipv4']['address']}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"
```

This way, if `cassandra_network_iface` is overridden per host, value from hostvars will be used; otherwise – default roles' value.